# Based index addressing in assembly for 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm a little confused about this following line:

```
add ax, [si+4]
```

Does this take the value of `SI` and add 4H to it, and then add that to `AX`?

For example, we'll say `AX` = 1000 and `SI` = 0010. What would `AX`'s value be?

Comment: the instruction you wrote will add ax to the 16-bit value at memory location (SI+4). To add SI+4 to ax, use the LEA instruction

Comment: That makes complete sense. I don't know why I was so stumped. Thank you!

Comment: 2BitBank: no, this is Intel syntax. Destination operand is first. It adds memory operand to the register, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes the value **at** SI+4 and adds it to AX. In other words, it adds 4 to SI, retrieves a 16-bit integer value from memory at that address (in the DS segment), and adds that value to AX.

We don't know what will be the value of AX because we don't know what's at address DS:0014. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of All this is Register Relative Addressing Mode not Based Index.

Assuming that the value of SI is 0010 and not 0010H

it would add 10+4=14 i.e. 'E'
so it would be DS:000E H

if you mean 0010H 
it would be DS:0014H

And at last whatever is in the data segment in the 15th Location in 1st Case and the 20th Location in the second  , the content of that will be added to AX.